# How to deploy a pre-compiled contract to hardhat node

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, hardhat

I have a proxy contract and would like to replace the underlying implementation contract.

I already have the abi & bytecode of a smart contract(retrieved from artifacts folder), so here is what I did:

```
const NFTv2 = await ethers.getContractFactory(upgradedContract.abi, upgradedContract.bytecode);
contract = await upgrades.upgradeProxy(proxyContract.address, NFTv2);
```

It works fine, but I don't want the contract to exist in my `contracts` folder, so I've deleted it and run `npx hardhat compile` again.

Now when I try to run this deploy script again, hardhat keep throwing this error:

```
Error: The requested contract was not found. Make sure the source code is available for compilation
      at getContractNameAndRunValidation (node_modules/@openzeppelin/upgrades-core/src/validate/query.ts:46:11)
      at Object.getStorageLayout (node_modules/@openzeppelin/upgrades-core/src/validate/query.ts:54:41)
      at Object.deployImpl (node_modules/@openzeppelin/hardhat-upgrades/src/utils/deploy-impl.ts:30:18)
      at Proxy.upgradeProxy (node_modules/@openzeppelin/hardhat-upgrades/src/upgrade-proxy.ts:36:22)
```

After some try & error, it seems to be related to the cache folder, once the related metadata inside the cache folder disappeared, then this error will pop out, otherwise no.

Can someone guide me on this problem and how can I deploy contract with only abi & bytecode without leaving the contract inside the `contracts` folder?

Thank you! :)

Here's the code of my upgraded contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache2.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC1155/presets/ERC1155PresetMinterPauserUpgradeable.sol";

contract Test is ERC1155PresetMinterPauserUpgradeable {
    string private _uri;

    event upgradeEvent(string);

    function uri(uint256) public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return string(abi.encodePacked(_uri, "/new"));
    }

    function seturi(string memory uri) public {
        emit upgradeEvent("this is an upgraded contract");
        _uri = uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: hey @johnhckuo did you manage to solve it? I have the same problem and I can't find a solution, thanks!

Comment: Have you take a look at this answer: 
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/83082/86303

and this tutorial: 
https://docs.avax.network/subnets/hello-world-precompile-tutorial#step-11-add-genesis